# reconciling Facebook PHP SDK with zend framework

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework, facebook-graph-api

so I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK for authenticating my user....

and I'm trying to logout my user using the `destroySession()` method in base_facebook.php

These are some relevant excerpts in the PHP SDK's base_facebook.php: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php

```
      public function destroySession() {
        $this->setAccessToken(null);
        $this->user = 0;
        $this->clearAllPersistentData();
      }

  protected function clearAllPersistentData() {
    foreach (self::$kSupportedKeys as $key) {
      $this->clearPersistentData($key);
    }
  }

  protected function clearPersistentData($key) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to clearPersistentData.');
      return;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    unset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]);
  }
```

but everytime I try to do so, Zend Framework would complain

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()' 

Zend_Session_Exception: session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()
```

How do I go about clearing my facebook session without triggering all these errors?

Comment: Do you have your own class that is extending BaseFacebook? Or are you extending the Facebook class (which in turn extends BaseFacebook)?

Comment: If Zend is throwing this exceptions you should check code and look for other possible session_start(), maybe in flashMessenger? By the way, this code is from class Facebook that extends FacebookBase. Maybe you should consider writting own class that store facebook data in session but with use of Zend Session mechanisms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prerequisite for using Zend_Session is the session must not be initiated yet. Facebook initiates it. As a solution, call [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before using Zend_Session.

Alternatively, call [session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to logout the facebook user. It destroys all of the data associated with the current session.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work with Zend_Session, I modified the facebook.php source code and replace

```
    session_start()
```

by

```
    $this->session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    $this->session->fb = array();
```

Then replace all occurences of

```
    $_SESSION"
```

by

```
    $this->session->fb
```